# Expression for joint p.d.f. of $(X_1^2,X_2^2)$ in terms of joint p.d.f. of $(X_1,X_2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to solve the next exercise:

Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random variables with joint p.d.f. f. Let $Y_1=X_1^2$ and $Y_2=X_2^2.$ Derive and expression for the joint p.d.f. of $Y_1$ and $Y_2.$

By definition $f_{(Y_1,Y_2)}(y_1,y_2)=P(X_1^2=y_1,X_2^2=y_2),$ but I don't think to take square roots be the best way to get a useful expression because, for example, if both random variables were continuous, utilizing change of variables or derivating distribution function, such expression will contain jacobians or derivatives of inverse transformations in addecuate domains. Then, if we take only such square roots, would have missing terms ( derivatives ).

I think the goal of this exercise is to give an expression in a general form in terms of the d.p.f. f.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

HINT

I would do this in two steps, to simplify my own thinking if nothing else.  Let $Z_i = |X_i|$ then by symmetry we have, for $z_1, z_2 \ge 0$:

$$f_{Z_1,Z_2}(z_1, z_2) = f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) + f_{X_1,X_2}(-x_1,x_2) +f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,-x_2) +f_{X_1,X_2}(-x_1,-x_2) $$

(I'm not exactly sure how to *prove* the above but it seems "obvious"... Sorry!)

Anyway now you have $Y_i = Z_i^2$ and more importantly it is invertible $Z_i = \sqrt{Y_i}$ where you pick the positive root per the usual convention.  So you can apply Jacobians to transform from $f_{Z_1,Z_2}$ to $f_{Y_1, Y_2}$.

It's been many years since I attempted that :) so I won't try here, but [these lecture notes](http://www.markirwin.net/stat110/Lecture/Section36.pdf) seem to give a recipe starting on p.7.